# System-wise large font for Windows modern apps & Start screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, accessibility

I bought an 8-inch Windows 8 tablet today. The font size for the icons on the Start screen and the Settings, and all modern apps generally, is too small. And there are LOTS of empty margins round the texts!

[My new Windows 8 tablet and Google Nexus 7]
[image: My new Windows 8 tablet and Google Nexus 7]

Is there any way to set system-wise large font on Windows 8? I can do that on Android and on iOS. I tried to find it but failed. If there is no such way, once again Microsoft is a serious LAGGING behind the competition, compared to Android and iOS.

I do NOT want to increase the font size for traditional desktop apps. Their layouts are not flexible so when the font is increased, their layouts usually are messed.